# Showing authorised content with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
app.controller('PageCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$state', 'USER_ROLES', 'AuthService',  function($scope,$stateParams,$state,USER_ROLES, AuthService){
  //console.log("Page Controller reporting for duty.");

  $scope.currentUser = null;
  $scope.currentUserExists = false; //<- defined in scope of PageCtrl
  $scope.userRoles = USER_ROLES;
  $scope.isAuthorized = AuthService.isAuthorized;

  $scope.setCurrentUser = function (user) {
    $scope.currentUser = user;
    $scope.currentUserExists = true; //<- set true here!!
  };
```

Now in my html code I'm doing:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="PageCtrl">
```

....

```
<div class="navbar-brand" ng-if="currentUserExists">Welcome!!</div>
<div class="navbar-brand" ng-if="currentUser.data.teacher._id">Welcome2!!</div>
```

Iv tried ng-show, and I'm trying both examples above to test it.

If i log to console currentUser within my js file everything appears to be working normal. But nothing will show on my page.
Am i missing something??

currentUser is json set like:

```
$scope.login = function (credentials) {
    AuthService.login(credentials).then(function (user) {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
      $scope.setCurrentUser(user);
      console.log("currentuser");
      console.log($scope.currentUser.data.teacher._id); //Yes its working...
    }, function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    });
  };
```

...

```
 authService.login = function (credentials) {


    return $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'proxy2.php',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      transformRequest: function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for(var p in obj)
          str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        return str.join("&");
      },
      data: {
        url: 'http://teach.classdojo.com/api/dojoSession?_u=tid',
        login: credentials.login,
        password: credentials.password,
        type: 'teacher'
      }
    }).success(function (res) {
        alert("login success");
        Session.create(res.teacher._id, "admin");
        return res.teacher;
    }).error(function (res) {
        alert(res.error.detail);
    });

  };
```

Comment: i think you shuld return a promisse from authService.login. Look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: The login works fine, I'm authenticated. Its just getting the welcome message to show (so i can display the username)

Comment: is $scope.setCurrentUser being called successfully from $scope.login? Add a consoloe log or alert(1) inside to check.

Comment: All I can think to try is ng-show="currentUser" but then your examples(nf-if) shuld have worked.

Comment: Are you getting currentUserExists as true? Try printing its state in your app function and in your html code.

Comment: No I'm not getting it as true. I don't think the $scope is accessible. But I can't understand why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand why the scope wasn't working on the page, apparently due to inheritence or maybe because i was using $scope in two controllers?

Anyway i solved it using a service:

```
$scope.login = function (credentials) {
    AuthService.login(credentials).then(function (user) {
      userService.setCurrentUser(user); //<----Added this
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);

    }, function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
    });
  };
```

...

```
 var updateUser = function() {
   scope.view.currentUser = userService.getCurrentUser();
 };
 scope.$on(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess, updateUser);
```

..

```
app.service('userService', function() {
  var currentUser = null;

  return {
    setCurrentUser: function(user) {
      currentUser = user;
    },
    getCurrentUser: function() {
      return currentUser;
    }

  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
<div class="navbar-brand" ng-if="currentUserExists==true">Welcome!!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be due to your setting a primitive value on the scope.

Try using view.currentUserExists instead- so set $scope.view = {currentUserExists: false} in the initialization and then $scope.view.currentUserExists = true in the promise resolution.

Comment: I just tried using $rootScope and that seems to be working. I have no idea why though

Comment: Is it something to do with calling the setCurrentUser from a different controller?
Its mentioned in this tutorial: https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec
But iv followed it